# The repository list source index list can't be downloaded

Tags: ubuntu

I have Mint Linux 16 Petra and decided to update the system.
I went menu/admin/update manager and opened the manager.
Then I clicked on refresh and the manager ran the update list of source links.
A progress bar showing files lists (downloading files etc) and before completing it stopped and an error box appears saying that it could not download all the repository indexes. And, yes the CAT 5 cable etc. is working since I can open a browser.

Is there a way to bulk download and replace the whole list without going through the painful task of opening a terminal and fixing the file line by line.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic way of fixing the list of repositories. You probably need to point the Ubuntu repositories used by Mint at `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/` instead of `http://releases.ubuntu.com/` since Ubuntu 13.10 (on which Petra is based) is no longer supported.

Given the lack of security support for Mint 16 now though, you should really upgrade to a later version of Mint.